# Using VLOOKUP across worksheets without referencing the original worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, vlookup, microsoft-excel-2016

I've got a workbook that runs a few macros to pull in copies of sheets from a number of other workbook. I'm trying to set up one file that users can copy to their project folders and then just use without having to set up `VLOOKUP` formulas every time. So they copy file NewProject.xlsm from the server to their project folder and then use the macros to pull in the different sheets they need, either from the 100 series, 110 series or 120 series workbooks that are on the server.

The 100 series workbook has a sheet named ItemsE in it and has `VLOOKUP` in two columns and data validation in another. When users pull in the 100_1A sheet into their project file, it pulls the `VLOOKUP`, but it references the original file.

The NewProject file also has the ItemsE sheet in it with all the same information. My question is, am I able to use the `VLOOKUP` formula in the 100 series workbook on the 100_1A and 100_1C sheets and have it reference the ItemsE  sheet in the NewProject file instead of the 100 series file? I originally put the following formula in the 100 series file.

```
=VLOOKUP(D24,ItemsE!A:C,2,FALSE)
```

When I open the NewProject file after importing the 100 series sheets I need into it, the formula reads:

```
=VLOOKUP(D22,'W:\Design\[C_DE100Series.xlsm]ItemsE'!A:C,2,FALSE)
```

Is there a way to fix this? Would it also work on Data Validation?

Thanks for the help, and sorry for the long explanation. If you need more information from me, let me know.

Comment: Maybe you can put some vba in the workbook so that when you import a sheet it doesnt do this. However, I dont think there will be an easy non code fix, most users when they import a sheet, will want the formulae on that workbook / sheet to still point where it originally did, otherwise things would get very messy quickly...

Comment: So I had another idea (especially since VBA is not one of my strong suites) - What I did was kept the second formula, and just edited the file name to ItemsE and copied the data out into that file.

What I am unsure of is if there is a way to use data validation cross files in the same way? When I try it says I can't use that sort of a reference.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a common name for the ItemsE in your worksheet formulas.

For example make the name refer to "place" 
When you drag a worksheet to the receiving workbook, the name defined for the receiving workbook, will not however be used, and "place" will still refer to the sending workbook's name definition.

You can have a macro that deletes the old location on that active sheet which has just been dragged to the receiving workbook.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names("place").Delete
```

When that happens, the already defined name in the receiving workbook will then be used.